# SQL DISTINCT MIN() - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, sql-server-2019

I have recently started learning SQL, set up a server, tried to get some practice with a kaggle DB I have found.

I would like to see the recorder on each lap (meaning track name field should be distinct), however it lists all lap records instead.

I have tried:

```sql
select distinct 
    r.name, min(t.fastestlaptime) as 'Fastest lap', d.surname,  d.driverId, r.year
from
    races r
inner join 
    results t on r.raceID = t.raceID
inner join 
    drivers d on t.driverID = d.driverID
where 
    (t.fastestlaptime not in ('\N'))
group by 
    r.name, d.forename, d.surname, d.driverId, r.year
order by 
    r.name
```

I get this result:

| name | Fastest lap | surname | driverId | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70th Anniversary Grand Prix | 1:28.451 | Hamilton | 1 | 2020 |
| 70th Anniversary Grand Prix | 1:29.465 | Verstappen | 830 | 2020 |
| 70th Anniversary Grand Prix | 1:29.477 | Albon | 848 | 2020 |
| Abu Dhabi Grand Prix | 1:26.103 | Verstappen | 830 | 2021 |
| Abu Dhabi Grand Prix | 1:26.419 | Pérez | 815 | 2021 |
| Abu Dhabi Grand Prix | 1:26.615 | Hamilton | 1 | 2021 |
| Australian Grand Prix | 1:28.321 | Villeneuve | 35 | 2006 |
| Australian Grand Prix | 1:28.336 | Pérez | 815 | 2017 |
| Australian Grand Prix | 1:28.416 | Glock | 10 | 2009 |

[image: 1]

ofc, I just copy pasted some of the results, there are 7.6k rows, instead of just showing the rows with unique track names.

Can someone please explain to me? I'm malding not understanding the concept :D

I would like to list distinct track names, and the lap record, name of the recorder, recorder ID and year next to it.

Comment: No need/use for select `distinct` here. the group by returns no duplicates. (group by combined with select distinct just raises many eye-brows.)

Comment: you want to `group by r.name` and then in `select r.name, min(fastestlaptime), <some more aggregate functions>`, see https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-aggregate-functions/

Comment: @jhole, yes that is how far I got as well, I was just a bit confused how to add the drivers name, etc.. afterwards to the final result,

With this, I have got the first part of what I have wanted, but now I can not see driver name, driver ID, year listed. What should I do to make that happen properly? :) without using bad practice

Comment: As an FYI, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: @SYN, well you have to use some aggregate function e.g. for the driver name, think what happens if two different drivers have exact same fastestlaptime, what is your expectation then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL distinct is redundant. You are grouping by "d.forename, d.surname,  d.driverId, r.year" besided "r.name", thus you would get the min() per:

r.Name and then per each name, d.forename, d.surname,  d.driverId, r.year as well. That means, for example say, Lando Norris didn't have the fastest on any tracks on any year but was on the grid, then you would also see all of Norris' fastest laps on all tracks on all years he was on the grid as well.

If what you want is to list who got the fastest lap on each track and the timing, each year then what you need is to get the min() per track, year and then get the other info of the driver. ie: (based on your current SQL without seeing actual data you have):

```
select fL.name, fL.FastestLap as [Fastest lap], 
   d.surname,  d.driverId, fL.year
from 
(select r.Name, r.raceId, r.Year, min(t.fastestlaptime) as FastestLap
from races r
inner join results t
on r.raceID=t.raceID
group by r.Name, r.raceId, r.Year) fL
inner join results t on t.RaceID = fL.RaceId 
    and t.fastestLapTime = fL.FastestLap
inner join drivers d on t.driverID = d.driverID
order by fL.name;
```

EDIT: Here is a sample with some sample data (I think data structures is odd, but anyway here it is):

```
SELECT fL.Name, fL.FastestLap AS [Fastest lap], d.driverName, d.driverId, fL.year
FROM(SELECT r.Name, r.raceId, r.year, MIN(t.fastestLaptime) AS FastestLap
     FROM races r
          INNER JOIN results t ON r.raceId=t.raceId
     GROUP BY r.Name, r.raceId, r.year) fL
    INNER JOIN results t ON t.raceId=fL.raceId AND t.fastestLaptime=fL.FastestLap
    INNER JOIN drivers d ON t.DriverId=d.driverId
ORDER BY fL.Name, fL.year;
```

| Name | Fastest lap | driverName | driverId | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AbuDhabi Grand Prix | 00:01:16.9850000 | Driver 3 | 3 | 2022 |
| AbuDhabi Grand Prix | 00:01:09.8800000 | Driver 4 | 4 | 2023 |
| Brasilian Grand Prix | 00:01:23.0300000 | Driver 1 | 1 | 2022 |
| Brasilian Grand Prix | 00:01:20.0000000 | Driver 2 | 2 | 2023 |
| Monaco Grand Prix | 00:01:39.5000000 | Driver 2 | 2 | 2022 |
| Monaco Grand Prix | 00:01:39.5000000 | Driver 3 | 3 | 2022 |
| Monaco Grand Prix | 00:01:00.0010000 | Driver 1 | 1 | 2023 |

[DBFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/R1LlnpOx)

Comment: You are correct, that is what I am trying to achieve :)
I get the following error:


Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: Probably because of the comma at the end of line 4?

Comment: Almost :D 

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "r.name" could not be bound.

Comment: @SNY, edited. It would be fl.Name since we are selecting from it and not r inside the subquery.

Comment: Now it runs, lot of results included \N ( i guess DNF on the race) -  so i got that removed
Now we are down to 198 rows (was 7.6k) however still some duplicates from the lapnames - https://imgur.com/a/JWoaALp

@CetinBasoz

Comment: @SNY, images are not good for code which is text. Can you please edit your questioan and share races, results, drivers content at least partially as text or create table\insert scripts (better). It is a little odd that you have year on races and not results.

Comment: @SNY, since you didn't share sample data, I made up one and edited the reply with a link to sample. As I noted before, study your structures, it looks a little bit odd. IMHO, year should be on results and races should be more like "tracks" with just Id and track info fields. ie: Silverstone should exists only once there but in your case it exists each year that a race took place there.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies!
Sadly I can't accept both as valid solutions, it doesnt let me, even tough they are!
Learnt so much just from these, they will be really usefull in future usecases ! :D
I am new to the site, so can't give upvotes yet, but siggemannen and cetin basoz your solutions are much appreciated!

I am actually quite surprised you both put so much effort into this, but I am truly happy to see it! Also thanks for everyone else for the explainations and tips! :D

I will dig deeper soon to figure out and understand both from syntax to syntax!
Have a great day everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want fastest lap per track? This is usually solved not by aggregates but with ROW_NUMBER(), something like:

```sql
select *
from 
(
        select  *
        ,   row_number() over(partition by name order by try_cast([Fastest lap] as time)) as sort 
        from (
        VALUES  (N'70th Anniversary Grand Prix', N'1:28.451', N'Hamilton', 1, 2020)
        ,   (N'70th Anniversary Grand Prix', N'1:29.465', N'Verstappen', 830, 2020)
        ,   (N'70th Anniversary Grand Prix', N'1:29.477', N'Albon', 848, 2020)
        ,   (N'Abu Dhabi Grand Prix', N'1:26.103', N'Verstappen', 830, 2021)
        ,   (N'Abu Dhabi Grand Prix', N'1:26.419', N'Pérez', 815, 2021)
        ,   (N'Abu Dhabi Grand Prix', N'1:26.615', N'Hamilton', 1, 2021)
        ,   (N'Australian Grand Prix', N'1:28.321', N'Villeneuve', 35, 2006)
        ,   (N'Australian Grand Prix', N'1:28.336', N'Pérez', 815, 2017)
        ,   (N'Australian Grand Prix', N'1:28.416', N'Glock', 10, 2009)
        ) t (name,[Fastest lap],surname,driverId,year)
    ) x
where sort = 1
```

This `row_number() over(partition by name order by try_cast([Fastest lap] as time))` creates a sort column from 1 to ... which groups by track name and then orders the results by the fastest lap. I use try_cast to avoid strange times, you should not use strings as well.

Then you have to wrap your select in a subquery because ROW_NUMBER() window function cannot appear directly in a WHERE clause, thus: `where sort = 1`

Comment: `select *
from 
(
        select  *
        ,   row_number() over(partition by name order by try_cast([Fastest lap] as time)) as sort 
        from (
        select r.name, min(t.fastestlaptime) as 'Fastest lap', d.surname,  d.driverId, r.year
  from races r
  inner join results t
  on r.raceID=t.raceID
  inner join drivers d
  on t.driverID = d.driverID
  where (t.fastestlaptime not in('\N'))
  group by r.name, d.forename, d.surname,  d.driverId, r.year
        ) t (name,[Fastest lap],surname,driverId,year)
    ) x
where sort = 1` 

Works perfectly! Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: How does it handle if 2 races have the exact same time? @siggemannen

Comment: it will just take one of the drivers randomly. if you want both races you can use DENSE_RANK() function instead. Btw, in your query, you don't need any group bys etc, since they are meaningless. Just use my query and change the values thing to your table names

Comment: @SNY, it doesn't. Instead get the min first and then make a join (see my reply above).

Comment: Will try that! Thank you!

Comment: @CetinBasoz I have tried, but I get a sintax error.

I will need some time to get around what is exactly happening and understand the whole concept :D - So this solution is a ranking solution, and yours is getting a table with a set of results, and later joining it with the driver's details - if I am not wrong.

Comment: @SNY, unintentionally there was a comma before "from", some good man edited and corrected. It happens when you copy&paste and edit. 
Yes, it first gets the fastest laps and then joins for drivers who did it.